# Calculate route between two point in Google Maps Api react with lng and lat

Tags: reactjs, maps

How can i do this in order the get the two points for  `<DirectionsRenderer directions={directionsResponse} />` if I have the lat and long for them both?

```
async function calculateRoute() {
    if (originRef.current.value === "" || destiantionRef.current.value === "") {
      return;
    }
    const directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const results = await directionsService.route({
      origin: originRef.current.value,
      destination: destiantionRef.current.value,
      travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    });
    setDirectionsResponse(results);
}
```

but instead of OriginRef and destinationRef to have lng,lat values?